# pictureBox.ImageLocation with asteriks

Tags: c#, visual-studio, picturebox

i'm considerably new to c# and Visual Studio so i got stuck on one problem. Is there a way to make this pictureBox propertie to locate any image file? Asteriks doesn't seem to work..

```
        this.pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "d:\\*.png";
```

The directory alawys consists of single .png file, though it changes name periodically.

Comment: ImageLocation is the path to the SINGLE image to be displayed, not a shortcut with wildcards to a directory containing images

Comment: I don't think that works. First, do you want to display the first image you can find, or all images that would be in a given pattern? Either way you would have to enumerate the directory contents and then go from there.

Comment: NO. As already commented it has to be a absolute frilename and not a relative one.

Comment: huh, well there's always one picture in the folder, but it often changes name, ill try lookng into enumeration of the directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use wildcards on a `PictureBox`, however [Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx) does support them. So you could use that like so:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\", "*.png");
if (files.Length > 0) {
    // File(s) were found. You can now either decide
    // which one to display or just display the first
    // one
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = files[0];
} else {
    // No files found. Display a default image or something
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

The [ImageLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.imagelocation(v=vs.110).aspx) property is the path to a single image resource (file or url).

You can use [Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx) to enumerate the file(s) in the target folder using wildcards.

Answer (score -2):

No.  [ImageLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.imagelocation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) must specify the location of a single file to be displayed.  If you wish to display multiple images, you will need multiple picture box controls.